# How to bypass datatable default sorting, and use SQL statement when sort

Tags: datatables

How can I use an SQL sorting statement when I have sorting options enabled on datatables? If I disable the `"bSort": false"` I lose the ability to sort my lists.

My settings/config for the datatables is:

```
    $('#sort_date').dataTable({
        "stateSave": true,
         "bSort": true,
        "aoColumnDefs": [{
            'bSortable': false,
            'aTargets': [-1]
        }],
        "oLanguage": {
            "oPaginate": {
                "sPrevious": "",
                "sNext": ""
            }
        },
        "iDisplayLength": 15,
        "aLengthMenu": [
            [15, 20, 25, -1],
            [15, 20, 25, "All"]
        ],
         "responsive": true
    });
```

Comment: You're missing `"bServerSide": true,` from the iniitialisation code, so you're not using server-side datatables processing.  I assume you populate the table using some other method and then call the init code. To do what I think you mean, you need to implement [server-side processing](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side) properly, ie use the API

Comment: Im getting a error using this code.invalid JSON response. im also loosing pagination options.

Comment: What did you do? Add `"bServerSide": true` and expect it to magically work?  You will have to change the way you populate the datatable - please ready my first comment fully.

Comment: ofcourse, when that was the awnser that was given.

Comment: It's not an answer, it's a comment.